# Frontend/Backend Serving on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: php, reactjs, localhost, apache2, port

I am working on my first web-project and therefore use an Ubuntu Server 20.04 with apache2. Now i struggle with the correct frontend/backend-serving of my website. Actually I can not communicate with my backend in a meaningful way.

What is the "correct" way to do so? My current structure is:

**Frontend** (ReactJS):

- webserver: apache2
- IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80

**Backend** (PHP):

- webserver: apache2 (I allowed port 8080 in the firewall)
- IP:

  - variant 1: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
  - variant 2: localhost:8080
  - variant 3: 127.0.0.1:8080

I tried some different approaches to access my backend, but all failed.

My first approach was to serve the backend on the same public IP (variant 1) as the frontend, which lead to having all backend-files public visible. For security reasons this seamed like a stupid idea to me.

So I tried variant 2 and 3, which both ended with the same effect, that I could not access the backend from the frontend any more. (I tried accessing the backend via React Axios on "http://localhost:8080/index.php")

How does it happen, that I can not access my localhost directly from the frontend?

Sorry if this question sounds stupid, but I am just about to learn about servers.

If you need more information, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that your front-end runs in users's browsers, so your api/backend needs to be as accessible as the the web server hosting your front-end.  To answer your question directly though will be a little difficult without knowing more about how your application is configured, what kind of error you're getting, if any, etc... 

Also have you tried accessing your backend code directly in a browser (not though your react app)?

Comment: From my understanding, you want to network your applications using ingress which `nginx` supports natively very well. It is pretty simple to configure a reverse proxy in front of your services and even front it with DNS. Utilise common products like `docker` and take a look at using [traefik.io](https://traefik.io/) which even offloads DNS. This way, you can have both services contained on `80/tcp` inside their own VLAN and then front it with one DNS record. Each container is networked allowing you make internal requests.

Comment: Thanks @bindlegrunt, I somehow missed the fact WHERE the front-end runs. I was thinking it is still my server, so from that point of view "localhost" makes absolutely no sense.

As long at is was served at the public IP there was no problem, accessing it, just over localhost/127.0.0.1 (makes sense now...)

Comment: Thanks @Jaquarh, I will have a closer look at your suggested methods and edit/answer the post afterwards, how I got it working!

Comment: I don't really use `reactjs` but I open-sourced an example with `laravel` you're [more than welcome](https://github.com/Kyle-Jeynes/Laravel-Dockerized) to reference to. The concept doesn't change. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

> My first approach was to serve the backend on the same public IP (variant 1) as the frontend, which lead to having all backend-files public visible. For security reasons this seamed like a stupid idea to me.

Public files need to be visible. That's what makes them public.

> So I tried variant 2 and 3, which both ended with the same effect, that I could not access the backend from the frontend any more. (I tried accessing the backend via React Axios on "http://localhost:8080/index.php")

Localhost means "The same computer as the client".

So it will try to access a server running on *the same computer as the browser*, not a server running on *the same computer as the server that hosted the HTML document referencing `localhost`*.